# Best practice for creating a primary key when the Unique Identfier is not sequential

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-design

I work for a call center and I'm building a new database for our call data that we download every 15 minutes from our provider.  They use a Long Int for the Unique Identifier but it appears they also use a load balancer.  So what happens is we get a bunch of sequential Call ID's and then get a set from a totally different pool.  (I.E. 11112, 11113, 11114, 11115, 71112, 71113, 11115, 71114, etc).  My concern is by setting the Call ID as the "Primary Key" the system will constantly be moving things around to keep them in order.  The table will easily grow to 50+ million rows.

Would I be better off just creating a non clustered unique index vs a Primary Key?  Or I could create my own Identity column for the Primary Key?

Love to hear best practice/opinions!

Comment: don't fix problems you don't have yet.  It's a good idea to be ready when / if it does hit.  But  a primary key simply needs to be non duplicated.  What does the system you use do when you reach 69999 on the first server set?  As an option you could partition the data by the server sets if you're concerned about the table reorganizing the data all the time.so from 1-69999 goes here...70-XXXXX goes to 2nd partition but I'm not sure you have a problem you need to address yet. As a rule of thumb I have my own identity key and set a unique index on foreign keys provided I KNOW they can't duplicate

Comment: I never know when we will have a need to pivot, so using someone else key limits my options.  Having my own internal key gives me greater flexibility and control.

Comment: A more realistic view of the data...
195300814639
195300814809
164878289395
195300818156
195300819405
195300822084
164878304631
164878308923
164878315665

Actually two call centers were bought by a bigger company and we both used the same call center provider.  Now we are moving both to a new instance of the system...so two DB's will be combined into one.  The "Unique ID" can now be duplicated so I will also have to add BusNo to the key if I stick with the Call ID.

Comment: my "best practice" is always have my own key.  if I'm embeding a key from another system I can set a unique index on it; but I don't want to rely on it.  also, do you need to handle the data as if it was immutable? So we pull in data... for 195300814639 then 15 minute we pull in data for 195300814639 as it's cahnged.  Do I need to know before and after?  Say before it had 2 "Notes" and now it has 3 but note 2 was deleted and notes 3,4 were added.

Comment: Technically we download "dirty" data.  One of the fields is not necessarily finalized so we also do a two day refresh in the early morning hours.  We don't care what the old values were...just the final answer.  I was leaning towards creating my own identity column as a Primary Key but the BusNo + CallID is 100% unique.  So would creating an Identity column as the Primary Key add any performance gains over only having a non clustered Unique Index on BusNo + CallID?  If I put them in a Primary key the DB will constantly be moving records around to maintain the physical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting data is the forte of a B+ tree, which is what SQL Server uses.  Don't worry about it.

If your server can't handle 500 million rows in 2022, it needs more RAM.  If we assume a 1KB record, your 50 million row table needs 50 GB on disk (more, actually, but usually less than 100 GB).  Your server should have twice as much RAM as that, at least.

If you use a nonclustered index, you *will* impede performance when you use it (versus clustered).  The DBMS has to first find the key in the index, then get the row from the table.  On insertion, it has to add the row, and then update the index, too.

> Or I could create my own Identity column

As a rule of thumb, *store what you know*. Don't add anything.  An identity column adds no information to the database: with it, you don't know anything you didn't know without it.  It just adds complexity, another column to manage and think about.

Your data can be reduced to BCNF using natural keys.  We know that's true, because it's true of all data.  The trick (and the skill) is finding that design.

Comment: I get store what you know.  But I also know my data providers have changed rules on me mid stream and I find out weeks/months later.  having a unique key I can manipulate / control when the change they made were "Keys" helped.  Never mind mergers where duplicate keys now beomes possible...  It just depends on what you're prepared for.  Personally, I like my on identity especially if their 1 key field becomes 4.

Comment: So I spent much of the day reading up on B Trees and indexing but I'm still not 100% clear.  I've read that a MS SQL Primary Key is the "physical order" on disk.  So by inserting non sequential keys...I'm not causing a bunch of overhead while the DBMS moves things around to make room?  How does that relate to the "padding" setting?  What would be a good setting for padding?  That's really what has me asking about using Identity keys etc.

Comment: Take care in your research to stick to B+ trees, not B trees in general.  In a B+ tree, the data are all in the leaf nodes.  Insertion involves finding space in that leaf node (and higher nodes, if they're full). Normally, that's cheap: find the node, and insert the row.  Padding determines how many empty rows are allowed for whenever a node is split.  Normally IIRC a new node is 50% full.  For static data, you can get denser representation for faster searches, at the cost of more expensive inserts.

Comment: @xQbert, if you don't enforce uniqueness of natural keys at insertion, it will only create problems down the line, when some join that should produce one row produces two.  When uniqueness rules change, *fail fast* is your friend. Add the distinguishing column, modify the key definition, and update the load procedure. Probably there will be other changes, too, but at least you'll know where to look.

Comment: I agree; I just don't like having to perform an update involving a 7 part key.  the surrogate key gets me away from that while yet allowing a unique index on the 7 part Logical/natural Key